# Jquery onclick with multiple different filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to use Jquery .onclick to use divs as buttons and when clicked, filter a bunch of data for the user. For instance, I have the category `Sports` and the sub-categorys `basketball` and `baseball`.

When the button is clicked I am trying to have an Ajax call to the database to filter all posts that involve the sub-category.

My question is, what is the best way to make this code as condensed as possible. If I click basketball or baseball can I send in a parameter to my php file from an Ajax call and have multiple if-statements for the different parameters in the php?

Here is an example of the divs:

```
<div class="filter" id="basketball">

</div>
<div class="filter" id="baseball">

</div>
```

If I can pass parameters through the AJax to the PHP then could I create one function in Jquery that handles the Ajax and do something like the following?

```
$('#basketball').click(myFunction(basketball)); 
$('#baseball').click(myFunction(baseball));

myfunction(parameter){
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "filter.php", //Send parameter in to php?
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) 
       {
          ...
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not being using IDs for this purpose.

Try this way:

```
<div class="filter" data-category="basketball">

</div>
<div class="filter" data-category="baseball">

</div>
```

On your javascript:

```
$('.filter').on('click', function(){
    var category = $(this).data('category');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "filter.php?category="+category, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) 
        {
           ...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Very nice. Quick question: in putting data before category (`data-category`) does that allow you to do the `$(this).data('category');` or can you always put `'category'` there?

Comment: This is called a [data attribute](http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/), an HTML5 feature.